# Split a list into individual characters in python

Tags: python, list

I have this list `['MEYFDAHCHLNCEPLLSEIEKSIANFKLINLKANVVGTDLDNSKIAVELAKKYPDLLKATIGIHPNDVHLVDFKKTKKQLNELLINNRNFISCIGEYGFDYHYTTEFIELQNKFFEMQFEIAETNKLVHMLHIRDAHEKIYEILTRLKPTQPVIFHCFSQDINIAKKLLSLKDLNIDIFFSIPGIVTFKNAQALHEALKIIPSELLLSETDSPWLTPSPFRGKVNWPEYVVHTVSTVAEIKKIEIAEMKRIIVKNAKKLFWH']`

I have saved it into a list called `proteinseq` and would like to split it individually to be able to print the first 20 chars only. How can I do this in python?

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service; do some research and make an effort.

Comment: Did you try something? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just have 1 item in your list.

```
proteinseq[0][:20] # Get up to the 20 characters from the 1st item in the list
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize the list had only one item. My professor was able to show me that i was only missing this [0] in my code. when added it worked.                                                                                        #translation table value and proteins
tablecds = record.features[21]
print("It is using translation table "+ str (tablecds.qualifiers["transl_table"]))
proteinseq=(tablecds.qualifiers["translation"][0])                             print("The first 20 characters of proteins are " + proteinseq[:20])